# QRubberBand, How to select items??? QT Docs do not help at all

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that has a GraphicsView on it, loads of dots are drawn onto the QGraphicsView and assigned some data using this code

```
void GUI::paintitem(double x, double y, double Id)
{

    // Decalre a QPen for Painting dots
    QPen pen;

    // set the pen colour
    pen.setColor(Qt::white);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem *item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem;
    item->setPen(pen);
    item->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
    item->setRect(x,y,1.5,1.5);
    item->setData(m_count, Id);
    item->ItemIsSelectable;


    if(x < m_height && y < m_width)
    {
        // Add ellipse at the x y position passed in
        scene2->addItem(item);
    }
    m_count++;
}
```

on my mouse event i have this

```
if(event->type() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        ui->graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
        QList<QGraphicsItem*> selected = ui->graphicsView->scene()->selectedItems();
    }
```

And the QList contains nothing when it should have all my items in it

looking at docs and demos that use this i cant find anything helpful on how the selection actually works,

any help would be appreciated cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
```

Comment: ok but im pretty sure that will change nothing because i have no idea how to make selection possible, as in, what is the code so that when i have highlighted the area of dots on my graphicsView that list i have declared actually gets filled with the items?

Comment: When you set the drag mode to QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag it should handle the selection by itself. In the mouse release event you can check for the selected items just like you did in your code. All you need to do is set the drag mode, and make sure that your items have the selectable flag turned on.

Comment: ok so on release i need to have the `QList<QGraphicsItem*> selected = ui->graphicsView->scene()->selectedItems();` and it should be populated with all the items ?

Comment: Yes. And on mouse press event you set the drag mode to QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag.

Comment: ok that seemed to work because i did a `.isEmpty' check on it and seemingly it is populated, you see how the items have data, how i now extract that from the QList now its populated?